# How to stop MIDI playback with a button?

Tags: blazor, midi

The example code is using DryWetMidi library. The program plays a MIDI file (MIDI.Path) on button click until the file ends. The problem is there seems to be no way of stopping the playback with another button.

Is there anyone who has experience with the MIDI library that knows how to make a button that stops the current file playback?

```
@using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia;
@using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Core;

<span @onclick="@(() => PlayMidi())">
    <button>Play</button>
</span>


@code{
    private static Playback playback;

    public void PlayMidi()
    {
        var midiFile = MidiFile.Read(MIDI.Path);


        var outputDevice = OutputDevice.GetByName("Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth");

        playback = midiFile.GetPlayback(outputDevice);
        playback.Start();

        SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => !playback.IsRunning);

        Console.WriteLine("Playback stopped or finished.");

        outputDevice.Dispose();
        playback.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The `playBack` and `outputDevice` objects are disposed within the `PlayMidi` function. This means that when you try to access the `playBack` object from outside of this function, it has already been disposed.
2. The play button does not finish execution until the midi is finished playing. This is because the `SpinWait` inside the `PlayMidi` function waits until the `playback.IsRunning` is false. In other words, if you call a function to stop the `playBack` object while it is playing, it will not stop until the midi has finished playing.

I have updated your code to properly dispose the objects. I also commented out the `SpinWait` part and included a stop button and `StopMidi` function. This will allow you to stop the playback, play again, and stop again as needed.

```razor
@page "/"
@using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia;
@using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Core;
@implements IDisposable

<span @onclick="@(() => PlayMidi())">
    <button>Play</button>
</span>

<span @onclick="@(() => StopMidi())">
    <button>Stop</button>
</span>


@code {
    private Playback playback { get; set; }
    private OutputDevice outputDevice = 
        OutputDevice.GetByName("Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth");

    public void PlayMidi()
    {
        var midiFile = MidiFile.Read("Midi/Cymatics - Waves MIDI 10 - E Min.mid");
        
        playback = midiFile.GetPlayback(outputDevice);
        playback.Start();

        //SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => !playback.IsRunning);

        Console.WriteLine("Playback stopped or finished.");
    }

    private void StopMidi()
    {
        playback.Stop();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        outputDevice.Dispose();
        if (playback != null)
            playback.Dispose();
    }
}
```